# bash: variable expansion inside var=$' '

Tags: bash

I'm almost certain the code I have here worked before.  Here's a simplified version and what it produces:

```
a="atext"
b="btext"
var=$'${a}\n${b}\n'
printf "var=$var"
```

Which produces output:

```
var=${a}
${b}
```

The real code outputs var to file, but the variable expansions aren't happening for some reason.

If this can't work, can you suggest a nice alternative way, and why one uses $' '?   Thanks.

GNU bash, version 4.3.42

Comment: `printf "var=$var"` isn't a great example here, if you want to show the string literally as constructed. Perhaps you want `printf 'var=%s\n' "$var"`, or `printf '%s\n' "var=$var"`?

Comment: Passing the expanded `$var` as the format string, you can't tell if the `\n` is literal or two separate characters at the time when it's passed to `printf` -- and if you're using it in a context where it can be two separate characters, then you don't have call to use `$''` to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$''` is a quoting type used to allow backslash escape sequences to describe literal strings with nonprintable characters and other such oddities. Thus, `$'\n'` evaluates to a single character -- a newline -- whereas `'\n'` and `"\n"` both evaluate to two characters, the first being a backslash and the second being an `n`.

---

If you want to have the exact behavior of your original code -- putting a **literal** newline between the results of two different expansions -- you can switch quote types partway through a string:

```
a="atext"
b="btext"
var="$a"$'\n'"$b"
printf '%s' "var=$var"
```

That is, right next to each other, with no spaces between:

```
"$a"
$'\n'
"$b"
```

This gives you `$a` and `$b` expanded, with a **literal** newline between them.

---

Why does this matter? Try the following:

```
$ a=atext
$ b=btext
$ var1="$a\n$b"        # Assign with literal "\" and "n" characters
$ printf "$var1"       # Here, printf changes the "\n" into the newline
atext
btext
$ printf '%s' "$var1"  # ...but this form shows that the "\n" are really there
atext\nbtext
$ var2="$a"$'\n'"$b"   # now, we put a single newline in the string
$ printf '%s' "$var2"  # and now even accurate use of printf shows that newline
atext
btext
```

Comment: Why is there a `$` in front of `'\n'`?

Comment: Someone downvoted you.  My question is when do you use a $ and single quotes?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, because it tells the shell to put a single, literal newline character in the string.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, ...otherwise, `\n` is two characters, a backslash and an `n`. The way the OP is using `printf` obscures the difference in the two constructions; I may end up amending this answer to explain it in more detail.

Comment: Or you could just do:
`var="${a}\n${b}"`
`printf "var=$var"`

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, that's only if the real use of the string is for `printf`, **and** if you're not worried about format string attacks.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, ...there's a reason that passing non-constant strings as the first argument to `printf` is considered bad practice.

Comment: So do you ALWAYS use a %s or %b, etc. with printf?

Comment: @Ray, unless the first argument is a constant, yes. `printf 'Hello\n'` is safe, because `Hello` is a completely known quantity, but `printf "$foo"` is bad practice, better written as `printf '%b' "$foo"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you seem to be getting on some tangents, the OP only wanted to know why variable expansion wasn't working. Your answer also changes the output from OP's code, whether or not that is for the better seems subjective.

Comment: If the question belies a misunderstanding, yes, I consider addressing that misunderstanding an aspect of providing a full and complete answer.

Comment: Your answer would be better if it said: `Here is why variable expansion isn't happening, but here is an even better way to write it` ... You don't ever actually say why variable expansion isn't working, which is the issue I have with this answer. That is the OP's original question.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, suggestion adopted.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, that said, I disagree that I failed to answer the question; the question wasn't why expansion wasn't happening, but how to make it happen (while also using `$''`). I answered that from the very first revision.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation as usual Charles.  I missed your comments to my question above, but see them now.  I appreciate your help.   I totally agree with your last comment.  I asked for "a nice alternative way" in my question.   I don't know who downvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the single quotes with double quotes.

```
$ cat test
a="atext"
b="btext"
var=$"${a}\n${b}\n"
printf "var=$var"
$ sh test
var=atext
btext
```

For variable expansion you either need to use double quotes or no quotes. Single quotes negate expansion.

Comment: This works for the example, but only because of the misuse of `printf`; `var` isn't getting the same value it would with the OP's original code. If you used `printf '%s\n' "var=$var"`, the difference between the two constructions of `var` would be obvious.

Comment: So what are the single quotes for with a leading $?  I see that in many answers.

Comment: @Ray, that depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish. If you don't know what the syntax does, you don't know if you need it, and you haven't told us enough about what your *real* goal is that we know if you need it either.

Comment: I have something just like that.  I must be confused.  When does one use a leading $ and single quotes?

Comment: @Ray $'string' is a string that interprets C-style escape sequences like `\n`, e.g. `$'foo\nbar'` is a string with a newline between `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Well that's good, but then variable substitutions aren't possible?

Comment: @Ray That's correct. You can do `"$foo"$'\n'"$bar"` if you want to substitute `$foo` and `$bar` with newline between them.

Comment: @Ray, see my answer as extended. (What Barmar is pointing out is, well, what that answer said back when I first wrote it).

Comment: I see ... I think.   Then why not just use a $" " instead?

Comment: @Ray, `$""` is something completely different (i18n support; it looks in a gettext translation table for a version of the string written for the current locale).

Comment: So I shouldn't use ryanpcmcqueen's way if I'm not doing i18n support?

Comment: @Ray, you shouldn't use `$""`, no; just `var="${a}\n${b}\n"`, without the `$` immediately before the `"`, would have the exact same results. (And to be clear, those results are a string that contains literal backslashes followed by "n" characters; it's only `printf` that makes them look like newlines).

Comment: @Ray, ...if you take the code in this answer, and then change `printf "var=$var"` to `printf '%s' "var=$var"` -- thus, printing the literal contents of the variable instead of using it as a format string -- you'll see what I mean above.

Comment: The argument against this answer, by the way, is that `foo="\n"` (like its i18n-enabled equivalent `foo=$"\n"`) assigns a different value than `foo=$'\n'` does. Thus, if the `printf` is only there for demonstrative purposes, the practice suggested here is not in fact a substitute for the `$''` quoting style given in the question (failing to fulfil its primary use case of allowing newlines and other nonprinting characters to be specified in literals in a visible and editor-friendly manner).

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy.